# Entity framework average , group by query

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

Hello i have the following query

```
        var myList = (from p in db.Full
                      where (p.date_reception > begin & p.date_reception < end & !p.mc_object.Contains("NULL")
                             & (!strListe.Contains(p.mc_object)))
                      group p by new { p.mc_object} into g

                      select g.OrderByDescending(p => new {p.duration,p.mc_object} ) into r
                      select new StringIntType
                      {
                          str = r.mc_object,
                          nbr = r.duration.Value
                      }).Take(50).ToList();
```

I need to group by mc_object , and select mc_object , average of duration
and order by average of duration descending ,Thank you for helping

Comment: Probably you can change `new { p.mc_object}` to `p.mc_object`

Comment: Here's a good example, try to follow it: http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/257/entity-framework-6-recipe-grouping-by-year-and-month

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query should be

```
var myList = (from p in db.Full

              // Don't use &! Use &&
              where p.date_reception > begin && 
                    p.date_reception < end && 
                    !p.mc_object.Contains("NULL") && 
                    !strListe.Contains(p.mc_object)

              group p by p.mc_object into g

              select new 
              { 
                  mc_object = g.Key, 
                  /* data = g, */
                  avg = g.Average(x => x.duration) 
              } into h

              // if you want both descending, add descending after mc_object
              orderby h.avg descending, h.mc_object 

              select new StringIntType
              {
                  str = h.mc_object,
                  nbr = (int)h.avg // Average returns a double
              }).Take(50).ToList();
        }
```

Note that I've changed the `&` to `&&`. For the ordering I wasnt sure. I dont need the full data in the second half of the query, so I've added a commented `data = g`